# How to use terraform's github_repository for already existing repositories?

Tags: github, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I use Terraform for creating non-existing repositories as below:

```
# main.tf
provider "github" {
    token = var.gh_token
    base_url = "#######My Company Base URL####"
    owner = "#####organization-name#####"
}


# repositories.tf
resource "github_repository" "terraform-created-repo" {
  name = "terraform-created-repo"
  description = "This is a description"
  visibility = "internal"
  auto_init = true
  has_issues = true
}


# variables.tf
variable "gh_token" {
  description = "Token for GitHub"
  type = string
}


# versions.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    github = {
      source  = "integrations/github"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Then run these commands

```
export TF_VAR_gh_token=....
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply
```

it creates the repository for me.

---

However, if I manually create a repository and want to add a description and other metadata as explained [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/resources/repository) it does not work because it complains

```
422 Validation Failed [{Resource:Repository Field:name Code:custom Message:name already exists on this account}]
```

How can I add such metadata data to a repository?

Note that I don't want to recreate the repository because I don't want the content of the repo to be lost. I just want to add the information to an already existing repository

Comment: You would have to use `terraform import` to tell terraform to start managing the state for it

Comment: @Paolo can I declaratively import it or do I have to use imperative command ?

Comment: You have to run it from the terminal

Answer (score 1):

The `terraform import` statements in this bash script will give you an idea of what needs to be done:

https://github.com/chrisanthropic/terraform-import-github-organization/blob/master/terraform-import-github-org.sh